# reading var in text/javascript on selenium java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have code in html like below:

```
<body>
     <script type="text/javascript">
            var result = {"products": [{
                                    "name": "SAMSUNG GALAXY J7 CORE GARANSI RESMI 1 TAHUN",
                                    "code": "6701800730440"
                                    },
                                    {
                                    "name": "IPHONE 6S 32GB GREY GARANSI INTERNASIONAL 1 TAHUN",
                                    "code": "3764942373363"
                                    }
                          ]};
     </script>
</body>
```

I try to return the value of var result using selenium

```
System.out.println(((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("return result;"));
```

to extract the value from the var result but the result is null
how can i retrieve data from var result and how i take data product [0] .name on java used selenium .

Comment: You could just grab the `SCRIPT` tag and load it as JSON. Then you could access anything you wanted.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to extract from _var result_? Entire text `"products": [{ ... "3764942373363" } ]};`

Answer (score 1):

> Data Class

```
public class NameCodeClass {

    public String name, code;

    public NameCodeClass(String name, String code) {
        this.name = name;
        this.code = code;
    }
}
```

> index.php

```
<body>
     <script type="text/javascript">
            var result = {"products": [{
                                    "name": "SAMSUNG GALAXY J7 CORE GARANSI RESMI 1 TAHUN",
                                    "code": "6701800730440"
                                    },
                                    {
                                    "name": "IPHONE 6S 32GB GREY GARANSI INTERNASIONAL 1 TAHUN",
                                    "code": "3764942373363"
                                    }
                          ]};
     </script>
</body>
```

> Test Function Using Selenimu

```
@Test
    public void test() {

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        driver.get("http://localhost/stackoverflow/index.php");

        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        Object productObject = js.executeScript("return result;");

        Gson g = new Gson();
        //Object to String convertion
        String productJsonString = g.toJson(productObject);

        JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
        //String to JsonObject Convertion
        JsonObject objectFromString = jsonParser.parse(productJsonString).getAsJsonObject();
        JsonArray jSONArray = objectFromString.getAsJsonArray("products");

        NameCodeClass product[] = new NameCodeClass[jSONArray.size()];//declaration and instantiation

        for (int i = 0; i < jSONArray.size(); i++) {

            objectFromString = jsonParser.parse(jSONArray.get(i).toString()).getAsJsonObject();

            product[i] = new NameCodeClass(objectFromString.get("name").toString(), objectFromString.get("code").toString());

            // System.out.println("name: " + product[i].name + "  code:" + product[i].code);
        }

        System.out.println("name: " + product[0].name + "  code:" + product[0].code);

    }
```

> Now you can call like  product[0].name  way